# How to list user_types used in a plsql script

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Do you know if it exists a way to show all the user types used in a plsql script (maybe using sqldeveloper)

Ty

Comment: This will be easier for a stored procedure/function/package than for a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the `user_dependencies` view (or [`all_dependencies`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F9EA7DFB-5471-4B07-BDEF-FDE5DF57D1F4.htm) or `dba_dependencies` if you can see it, and want to cast your net wider) to see which objects depend on each other.

To see all packages, procedures, functions and triggers (i.e. stored PL/SQL) that refers to user-defined types you can do something like:

```
select type, name, referenced_type, referenced_name
from user_dependencies
where type in ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY', 'TRIGGER')
and referenced_owner = user
and referenced_type = 'TYPE';
```

If you're interested in a particular 'script' (which has to be stored PL/SQL, not an anonymous block) then you can filter for that:

```
select referenced_name
from user_dependencies
where type = 'PROCEDURE' -- or whatever the object type actually is
and name = 'SOME_PROCEDURE' -- your actual object name
and referenced_owner = user
and referenced_type = 'TYPE';
```

In SQL Developer you can also find the procedure by drilling down into the connection in the left-hand panel and clicking on the procedure (or package, or whatever) name, which will open a new tab that shows the procedure code by default. Withing that tab there is a smaller set of tabs. Click 'Dependencies' and you'll see similar information to what that query gives you. If you're looking for dependencies from a package you may need to look at the body's dependencies as well as the specification's.